# how to generrate array of integers (exact same every time)?

Tags: c++, c, random, vb6

I am trying to generate array of integers within specific limit using random number generator but I want exact same array every time .

Comment: what did you try? Could you post the code? Also, i dont understand, if you want the same array every time, why you want that it be random? could you expand?

Comment: Make the seed of [srand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand)  the same.

Comment: How about writing a script to generate the array, save it to a file and then read it from your program?

Comment: @HonzaDejdar: And what would that second program be need for if you already have a program generating that file?

Comment: @Olaf Maybe he wants the same input for multiple runs of the program? That's what I would do, as it seems most straight-forward to me. Of course seeding the generator with the same seed will work as well.

Answer (score 4):

Seed your generator with the same seed value every time and it will produce the same sequence of numbers (true for *most* generators).

Comment: Wrong for true RNG! Only correct for **Pseudo**RNGs.

Comment: @Olaf hence my note in parens.

Comment: For the standard C `rand` generator it it not true for _most_, but for _all_. I'd be careful about others. How you know the majority are PRNGs?

Comment: It is easy enough to write a simple PRNG.  A linear congruential PRNG may suffice, or else one of Marsaglia's XOR-shift generators.  Given the same seed, such a generator will produce the same output sequence.

Comment: @Olaf  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Why cite a 2nd source instead of the only authoritative, the standard? Not sure what you try to prove by this. I already steated the standard random number generator **is** a PRNG. But that still does not prove others are, too. Nor that _most_ of them are! You never use the C or C++ standard PRNGs if you need a high quality PRNG and definitively not if you need a true RNG (which is pretty challenging to write ona a digital machine actually). For the latter it is best to use a distinct hardware device (some CPUs have some analog parts for that integrated).